# selectByVisibleText method with incorrect option text doesn't generates error using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html-select, webdriverwait

When I am trying to find element using `selectByVisibleText()` method from a dropdown, the program is getting executed even if there is no such text in the dropdown. Though after execution of program it is showing an error.

HTML element:

```
<select id="portfolioid">
    <option value="2021218" selected="selected">Ishu8</option>
    <option value="2021219">Ishu7</option>
    <option value="2021220">Ishu6</option>
    <option value="2021221">Ishu</option>
</select>
```

My Code:

```
WebElement wb=driver.findElement(By.id("portfolioid"));
Select dropdown=new Select(wb);
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Ishu1");
```

This is selecting the first element(i.e. "Ishu8") in dropdown and executing rest of the program, while it should stop the execution after an error. Rest of the scenarios are working fine

Comment: it should work i realy dont see what's causing this probleme i even tried it on my computer and it returns the error

Answer (score 0):

To select the [select-options](/questions/tagged/select-options) **Ishu1** from a [html-select](/questions/tagged/html-select) tag you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visIshu1ible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *id*:

  ```
  new Select(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("portfolioid")))).selectByVisibleText("Ishu1");
  ```
- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  new Select(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("select#portfolioid")))).selectByVisibleText("Ishu1");
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  new Select(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//select[@id='portfolioid']")))).selectByVisibleText("Ishu1");
  ```

Comment: My question was, that there is no "Ishu1" in the dropdown, so when I write driver.selectByVisibleText("Ishu1") it should throw an error and the execution of the program should stop then and there. But in my case it is selecting the very first element from the dropdown and executing the whole program. After the program has been executed it shows an error. So basically I want an error to be thrown and the execution of the program should stop then and there when there is no such element.